# Unable to escape command in windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, command, escaping, character

I've been stuck trying to pass a command like below to my application through cmd. I tried every single solution I could found but none worked, unfortunately!

```
run.py -- -command "func1(\"do this -and that\"); func1(\"do this -and that\");"
```

However, what I get in my application is this. Both commands are exactly the same. But I cannot figure out why rest of the second function does not get passed through!

```
func1("do this -and that"); func1("do this -and;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: Oh that did it! Thanks for saving my day! Actually I had looked at it already  but never tried the "" instead of \" and was thinking something else might be wrong.

Comment: It would appear that you are passing in "code" to execute. This would probably be considered a security risk.